# Vagrant machine runs out of memory when building singularity container

Tags: vagrant, singularity-container

I'm running vagrant on a Mac to create a singularity container – but running out of memory. I'm running:

```
sudo singularity build MY_CONTAINER.sif Singularity.recipe
```

I get this error:

```
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
FATAL:   While performing build: while creating squashfs: create command failed: exit status 1: 
Write failed because No space left on device

FATAL ERROR:Failed to write to output filesystem
```

But, the container should not be more than 10-20G – and I have given the vagrant machine more than 200G.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           222G        282M        220G        552K        878M        220G
Swap:          979M          0B        979M


vagrant@vagrant:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          111G     0  111G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          23G  552K   23G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root   19G  2.7G   15G  16% /
tmpfs                         112G     0  112G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         112G     0  112G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
vagrant                       932G  749G  184G  81% /vagrant
tmpfs                          23G     0   23G   0% /run/user/900


vagrant@vagrant:~$ pwd
/home/vagrant
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo singularity build --tmpdir '/dev' MY_CONTAINER.sif Singularity.recipe
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by specifying saving the .sif container where there was space:

```
sudo singularity build --tmpdir '/dev' /dev/MY_CONTAINER.sif Singularity.recipe
```

Comment: It might be helpful to also list the final size of the .sif image and the `df -h` output after the successful build so that folks know the space requirement.